# CakePHP : Why they use className with first brackates ()?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have used a cakephp method to change layout. Here it's looking like

```
$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');
```

I have seen [viewBuilder Class](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.ViewBuilder.html#155-166), where they haven't use any construct. Then for calling method `setLayout` why do I need to use className like `viewBuilder()`. At first I thought it's a nested method, but it's not.

Comment: Looks like `$this->viewBuilder()` is a method that returns an instance of the view builder class. The reason for that is most likely for making it easy for the developers (you don't need to instantiate the class and pass it around yourself) and to make sure the same view builder instance is used each time it's called (singleton.)

Comment: It's a class : https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.ViewBuilder.html#155-166

Comment: `$this->viewBuilder()` is a _method_ that _returns_ a class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API at [cake.org](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/), you can see that method(**not class**) `viewBuilder()` is defined in trait [`ViewVarsTrait`](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.ViewVarsTrait.html#51-63) and returns a `ViewBuilder` object (i.e. gets you the view builder being used).

This `ViewBuilder` object has access to method `setLayout()`.

This is why you use: `$this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('admin');`

from [source at cakephp.org](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/source-class-Cake.View.ViewVarsTrait.html#51-63)

```
 26: trait ViewVarsTrait
 27: {
     ...
/**
 52:      * Get the view builder being used.
 53:      *
 54:      * @return \Cake\View\ViewBuilder
 55:      */
 56:     public function viewBuilder()
 57:     {
 58:         if (!isset($this->_viewBuilder)) {
 59:             $this->_viewBuilder = new ViewBuilder();
 60:         }
 61: 
 62:         return $this->_viewBuilder;
 63:     }
     ...
```

*note: for more info on what [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are and how to use them.*